# Writing a scala method that can accept subclass of RuntimeException

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to write a scala method which can take any child of RuntimeException. I have it but it does not compile. What is wrong in the code?

```
def testme(e: RuntimeException): String = {
    case e:BadRequestException=> "bad request"
    case e: IllegalArgumentException=>"illegal argument"
}
```

I get the below error

```
missing parameter type for expanded function
[error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
[error] Expected type was: String
[error]   def testme(e: RuntimeException): String = {
[error]                                             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (playWeb/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Sep 21, 2017 2:45:09 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify what you are matching on, e.g. add an `e match`:

```
def testme(e: RuntimeException): String = e match {
    case e:BadRequestException=> "bad request"
    case e: IllegalArgumentException=>"illegal argument"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is Scala's pattern matching going to match the exact subclass instance with this check or it might not?

Comment: If you do `e: BadRequestException`, that will match if `e` is an instance of `BadRequestException` or any of its subclasses. Cases are matched against in-order, so put more specific cases first.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that I get. Essentially the strictest(or the most child class) first is what you meant. I was getting confused if by passing RuntimeException it can still match and I think it will. Else what is the point anyways

Comment: or `val testme: RuntimeException => String = { case ... => ... }` if all possible case are taken in account, or `val testme: PartialFunction[RuntimeException, String]` otherwise